# jwt-auth in not installing for laravel (6.0.3)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I im trying to install jwt-auth for laravel (6.0.3) but the composer giving me this error `Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.0.3, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.3].`

Comment: update your php version.because your php version is lower.

Comment: phpinfo() saying `PHP Version 7.3.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version JWT package was tagged for laravel 6!

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.x-dev
```

Refer this link https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1860